# Script fires too much?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey so I'm quite a noob but I was wondering if the script below didn't fire too much? And if so, can someone help me optimise it?

```js
<script>
jQuery(function() { 

  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if((jQuery(".main-content").height() - jQuery(window).scrollTop()) < 702) {
      jQuery("h1.product-single__title, .product-single__title.h1").addClass('titleScroll');
      jQuery("#ProductPhotoImg").addClass('imgScroll');
      jQuery("div#option_total").addClass('optionScroll');
      jQuery(".template-product .product-form__item--submit, .template-product .product-form__item--quantity").addClass('addScroll');
    }
    else {
      jQuery("h1.product-single__title, .product-single__title.h1").removeClass('titleScroll');
      jQuery("#ProductPhotoImg").removeClass('imgScroll');
      jQuery("div#option_total").removeClass('optionScroll');
      jQuery(".template-product .product-form__item--submit, .template-product .product-form__item--quantity").removeClass('addScroll');
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try lodash or underscore `throttle`. http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Comment: Underscore is a great library to use in general. I love throttle.

Comment: Beyond jquery the OP has not requested a library solution. It would be a significant overhead to have to take on a new library for one function.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Which is why I didn't create an answer with that solution, just a comment. It's always good to know about something as an option.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat if the OP *had* requested a library, it would have been closed as off-topic... such is the fickleness of SO

Comment: You have two options: throttle or debounce.  In this case, I'd recommend debounce over throttle (some implementation of throttle may actually be debouncing, I've not checked the suggested plugin above).  Throttle means - run this, then don't run it again while running or within x-ms.  Debouce means - run this after x-ms, if another event comes in, cancel the first/previous calls and only run the last.  This is ideal for mouse events as the last run uses the current/final position.

Comment: @freedomn-m Lol. I had to comment because the OP 'should' be told that there is a 'native' solution, particularly when it explains a technique that can be adapted for other purposes. I see too many times that folks suggest library solutions that are quite possibly not appropriate in a sledgehammer-nut kind of way. Equally I am not a purist and I use many libraries myself  if it gets me a robust and better-than-homegrown solution. Your longer comment would be perfect, imho,if you had started with 'You can do this natively with JS but the larger picture is...'. I upvoted you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

From https://dannyvankooten.com/delay-scroll-handlers-javascript/

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        // actual callback
        console.log( "Firing!" );
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called "throttling". By throttling a function, it only get's triggered x times per second, where you can define x. There are multiple ways of going about this and also a lot of libraries offer this functionality. You can find a nice read here on [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) which focusses on the lodash implementation.

Another great way to save performance is using `requestAnimationFrame()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)). This way you don't have to listen to scroll events, but you can tell the browser to perform some script on the *next repaint*. You could use it like so:

```
function doThis(){
   // javascript you'd like to trigger

   window.requestAnimationFrame(doThis); // call again to create a 'loop'
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(doThis); // initial call to get the 'loop' started
```